# initialize method to register with wifip2p framework in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, wifi-direct, looper

I am trying to call initialize method in my fragment class but it is saying that getMainLooper is undefined for this class.

```
private void initializeWiFiDirect() {
        wifiP2pManager = 
          (WifiP2pManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);

        wifiDirectChannel = wifiP2pManager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), 
                  new ChannelListener() {
                    public void onChannelDisconnected() {
                     initializeWiFiDirect();
                    }
                  }
                );
      }
```

Please help.

Comment: Just replace `getMainLooper()` with `getActivity().getMainLooper()`

Answer (score 2):

You can change it this way -

```
this --> getActivity().getApplcationContext()  // basically context.
                                               // you could use BaseContext too.
```

and `getMainLooper --> getActivity().getMainLooper()`

```
Channel wifiDirectChannel = wifiP2pManager.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), getActivity().getMainLooper(), 
              new ChannelListener() {
                public void onChannelDisconnected() {
                 initializeWiFiDirect();
                }
              }
            );
```